# use of for_each in a partial copy

Tags: c++11, vector, foreach, copy, mask

I have some old C code that still runs very fast. One of the things it does is store the part of an array for which a condition holds (a 'masked' copy)

So the C code is:

```
int    *msk;
int     msk_size;
double *ori;
double  out[msk_size];    

...   

for ( int i=0; i<msk_size; i++ )
    out[i] = ori[msk[i]];
```

When I was 'modernising' this code, I figured that there would be a way to do this in C++11 with iterators that don't need to use index counters. But there does not seem to be a shorter way to do this with `std::for_each` or even `std::copy`. 
Is there a way to write this up more concisely in C++11? Or should I stop looking and leave the old code in?

Comment: `boost` acceptable?  A filtrr iterator might be what you want, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `std::transfrom`.

```
std::array<int, msk_size> msk;
std::array<double, msk_size> out;
double *ori;

....

std::transform(std::begin(msk), std::end(msk), 
               std::begin(out), 
               [&](int i) { return ori[i]; });
```

Comment: filter, not transform methinks.

Comment: that sounds great, thanks! yuxiu, is array better for this example than vector? @yakk, could you explain what would filter do (better) that transform does not?

Comment: Array is better when the dimensions are known at compile time. Otherwise you should us a vector.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to modernize the loop, and keep the `ori` and `msk` data around, use @YuxiuLi's solution. If you also want to modernize the generation of the `msk` data, you can use `std::copy_if` with a predicate (here: a lambda that keeps only the negative numbers) to filter the elements directly.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    auto ori = std::vector<double> { 0.1, -1.2, 2.4, 3.4, -7.1 };
    std::vector<double> out;

    std::copy_if(begin(ori), end(ori), std::back_inserter(out), [&](double d) { return d < 0.0; });
    std::copy(begin(out), end(out), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ","));
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e015deb307284bc8). This saves an intermediate storage of `msk`.